# Red black node's struct alignment in linux kernel

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, binary-tree, red-black-tree

The defination of rb_node in linux kernel is as follow:

```
struct rb_node {
    unsigned long  __rb_parent_color;
    struct rb_node *rb_right;
    struct rb_node *rb_left;
} __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(long))));

#define rb_parent(r)   ((struct rb_node *)((r)->rb_parent_color & ~3))
#define rb_color(r)   ((r)->rb_parent_color & 1)
#define rb_set_red(r)  do { (r)->rb_parent_color &= ~1; } while (0)
#define rb_set_black(r)  do { (r)->rb_parent_color |= 1; } while (0)
```

My question is about `__rb_parent_color`, of which the last bit is the color and the rest is a pointer to its parent.

I learned someone say the last 2 bit of `__rb_parent_color` is useless because of `aligned(sizeof(long))` , but why?

Is not `sizeof(struct rb_node *)` 4 or Is not `sizeof(unsigned long)` 4? Even they are not equal, should `aligned` in **Byte** and if not aligned there will be at least one whole Byte is useless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__attribute__((aligned(sizeof(long))))` tells the compiler to ensure that the size of `struct rb_node` is always going to be at least a multiple of `sizeof(long)`.  See [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

That point is somewhat irrelevant though (because the pointers are at least `sizeof(long`). And looking at the source, you left out the most important part:

```
/* The alignment might seem pointless, but allegedly CRIS needs it */
```

---

The key to this implementation working, is that `struct rb_node`s will always be allocated on addresses that are at least 4-byte aligned. This is [guaranteed](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0103.0/0812.html):

> 4-byte alignment is guaranteed on 32-bit cpus, 8-byte alignment on 64-bit cpus.

For example, a node pointer might be like `0xF724315C`, which in binary ends in `...1100`.

That means that the last two bits of *any* pointer to a `struct rb_node` will be zero.  Because of this, the developers decided to use those two bits for something else (here, the color.)

We see this in the following [macro](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.7/include/linux/rbtree.h#L47):

```
#define rb_parent(r)   ((struct rb_node *)((r)->__rb_parent_color & ~3))
```

To get the parent node, one uses that macro which ands off the lower two bits.

Comment: I think i get it: the pointer save a node's address, which is multiple of 4(100) because of alignment of 4, so the value of a pointer will always like 100, 1000, 1100, 10100100. and is always end with 00. thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, sounds like you've got it. Remember that the `aligned(sizeof(long))` doesn't really matter here - this is really a function of `kmalloc`'s aligned allocations.